# Swift - UISearchController with separate searchResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to use UISearchController when you want to display the results in a separate searchResultsController - every single guide, video and tutorial I've found have all used the current viewController to present the search results, and instantiate UISearchController like so:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

but I want to dim the view and present a new tableView with the search results, in the same way done on the App Store search. So what I've done is created a new tableViewController, given it a storyboard id, and then instantiated it like so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let resultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchResults") as! UITableViewController
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController )
```

which seems to work. However, I'm pretty stuck from here on out. I have no idea how to display the search results in the resultsController, what to put in cellForRowAtIndexPath in the resultsController and so on.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 19):

Managed to figure it out -

1) add this line when instantiating the searchController:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```

2) add UISearchResultsUpdating to your resultsController like so:

```
class resultsController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
```

3) add this function, also in your resultsController:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

}
```

From there, you can get the search text, do stuff with it, and reload the tableView:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!

    //Do Stuff with the string

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone out!

Comment: How would you parse information from there back to the initial ViewController? For example when a UITableViewCell is selected?

Comment: With a custom protocol or via didSelectRow and then programmatically dismiss it and parse the result back to the initial VC?

Comment: is it possible to have UISearchController switch between 2 search results views using a segment control?

Comment: It did help me, Thanks